# How to get Page property within Razor component view?

Tags: dxa, sites-9, dxa2.2, dxa-dotnet

Pagemodel with default properties contains

{PageModel: 417519 ('Home pagina')}

> ExtensionData: null
> HasNoCacheAttribute: false
> **HtmlClasses: "hom_"**
> Id: "417519"
> IsVolatile: false
> Meta: Count = 6
> MvcData: {mymodule:Page:HomePage}
> ..

What statement can I use to get Page.HtmlClasses within Razor component view ?

Next statement doesn't works (need value from Page model)

> **@(Page.HtmlClasses)@(Model.HtmlClasses)@tegel.Id**

Example for extending tile-id.
Next statement works

> **@(Model.HtmlClasses)@tegel.Id**

```
                <bgl-tile tile-title="@tegel.Title"
                          tile-description="@tegel.Text"
                          tile-url="@tegel.Link"
                          tile-id="@(Model.HtmlClasses)@tegel.Id">
                </bgl-tile>
```

second question:

Can I declare within Razor Page view variable or extend the page model with property and use that later in Razor component view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Region and Entity Views primarily work on Region and Entity Models, respectively.

However, both have access to the entire context Page Model through the `WebRequestContext.PageModel` property.